# How to remain the size of grid items when the grid track shrinks in response to diminishing viewport resolution?

Tags: html, css

I took the desktop first approach to add responsiveness to my webpage. However, as the viewport resolution reduces before reaching the break point 720px, the "**tab section**" in picture 1(grid name: "**tabs**") below shrinks accordingly. Is there any way to keep its size even if it becomes greater than the grid track size as shown in the second picture(the grid item is greater than the track in size but doesn't break into two lines)? By the way, I am also trying to figure out how to keep the text in **meta** section from breaking onto the next line until it reaches the break point(please take a look at the second picture). Any tip on how to achieve is welcome.
[image: Layout skeleton]
[image: Picture 2]

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;
  gap: var(--gap,1rem);
}
.container-tabs * {
  background-color: transparent;
  border:none;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.content-meta {
  --gap:2rem;
}
.content-meta p {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

@media (min-width: 720px) {
  .grid-container {
    display:grid;
    column-gap: 2rem;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(2rem, 1fr) repeat(2,minmax(0,30rem)) minmax(2rem, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas:
       '. title title .'
       '. image tabs .'
       '. image content .';
  }
  .grid-container > .container-title {
    grid-area: title;
  }
  .grid-container > .container-image {
    grid-area: image;
  }
  .grid-container > .container-tabs {
    grid-area: tabs;
  }
  .grid-container > .container-content {
    grid-area: content;
  }
  .container-image {
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="testing.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="grid-container">
    <h2 class="container-title">Pick one planet</h2>
    <img class="container-image"src="https://i.ibb.co/F80STD5/image-mars.webp" alt="LOGO">
    <div class="container-tabs">
      <button type="button">Moon</button>
      <button type="button">Mars</button>
      <button type="button">Titan</button>
      <button type="button">Europa</button>
    </div>
    <article class="container-content">
      <h1>MARS</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
      <div class="content-meta flex">
        <div class="">
          <h2>Avg. distance</h2>
          <p>225 mil. km</p>
        </div>
        <div class="">
          <h2>Est. travel time</h2>
          <p>9 months</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to add the property "white-space: nowrap;" to each text element you want to keep from breaking line. Of course you should only give it to them at the breakpoint you need them to stay on one line.

Comment: Thanks it works for the text in meta section but the buttons in the tab section still bend and break onto the second line when viewport resolution reduces before break point.

Comment: If you want the buttons to always stay on 1 line just give "display: flex;" to the .container-tabs that contains them